# Separar texto en dos columnas

Tags: sql-server

Tengo una tabla donde se insertan la colonia y ciudad siempre con este formato:

> Columna Ciudad
>
> Colonia / Ciudad /

logré separar la colonia de la iguiente manera:

```
SUBSTRING(D.Ciudad,1,CHARINDEX('/',D.Ciudad) - 1) as Colonia
```

necesito separar la Ciudad y se quede en el Campo de Ciudad

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y cual seria el problema? porque es la misma instruccion lo que necesitas, solo cambiando desde donde tomas y hasta donde

Comment: Puedes usar la funcion split de sql y ya tendrias los datos separados

Comment: lo tengo dentro de un select en un SP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separar un texto en columnas es algo muy básico, pero hacerlo de manera robusta no lo es tanto. Dices que tu texto siempre tiene un formato constante, pero en mi experiencia nunca es así. Por lo tanto, empecé creando algunos datos de prueba con lo que pudiera pasar.

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING( D.Ciudad, 0, CHARINDEX( '/', D.Ciudad)) AS Colonia,
    REPLACE( SUBSTRING( D.Ciudad, CHARINDEX( '/', D.Ciudad), 8000), '/', '') AS Ciudad
FROM (VALUES('Colonia / Ciudad /'),
            ('Solo Colonia //'),
            ('Solo Colonia y un divisor /'),
            ('Solo Colonia SIN divisor'),
            ('/Solo Ciudad/'),
            ('/Solo ciudad sin divisor final')) D(Ciudad);
```

Ahí encontré que una fila no funcionaba como esperaba, así que tuve que agregar un par de funciones extra.

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING( D.Ciudad, 0, ISNULL( NULLIF( CHARINDEX( '/', D.Ciudad), 0), 8000)) AS Colonia,
    REPLACE( SUBSTRING( D.Ciudad, ISNULL( NULLIF(CHARINDEX( '/', D.Ciudad), 0), 8000), 8000), '/', '') AS Ciudad
FROM (VALUES('Colonia / Ciudad /'),
            ('Solo Colonia //'),
            ('Solo Colonia y un divisor /'),
            ('Solo Colonia SIN divisor'),
            ('/Solo Ciudad/'),
            ('/Solo ciudad sin divisor final')) D(Ciudad);
```

Uso la combinación de ISNULL/NULLIF para manejar los casos en los que no hay separadores en el texto. También uso 8000 porque es el límite básico de varchar (cuando no se usa MAX) y además el lugar con el nombre más largo en el mundo es de 176 caracteres por lo que no necesitas más de 8000.

El SUBSTRING con inicio en cero, evita la necesidad de restar a la longitud y así prevenir errores sin necesidad de validaciones extra.

Tal vez necesitas que la funcionalidad sea distinta, pero esto es lo básico.

Comment: esta fue mi solución:      substring(D.Ciudad,charindex('/',D.Ciudad)+1,charindex('/',D.Ciudad)-1) as Ciudad

Comment: Temo decirte que tu solución está mal porque estás usando la longitud de la colonia para generar la longitud de la ciudad. Puedes revisar con los datos de prueba que puse, aunque tu código genera un error cuando no hay diagonales.

Comment: siempre hay diagonales, asi se insertan los datos siempre

Comment: Pero igual permanece el error de la longitud.